# where is the global and static variables stored in memory segment?

Tags: c++, operating-system

In my linker script the starting address and size are as follows:

```
code start:90400000
code end:  90a00000
data start:90b00000, size 3MB
bss start: 91200000, size 1MB
```

But when I am declaring a global variable,its address is : `910bead0`
It is supposed to reside in `.bss` section ,but it is somewhere else, which I have not even specified in linker script.
Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Generate a map file during the link.

Comment: Note: `0x910bead0 - 0x90b00000 == 0x5BEAD0 == 6023888` which is about 6MB.

Answer (score 3):

You don't indicate what system, etc., you are using, but traditionally: initialized global data goes in `data`; uninitialized global data goes in `bss` (which will be 0 initialized).  When you write something like:

```
int x = 0;
```

systems differ: some recognize that the initialization is the equivalent to zero initialization (i.e. what happens when you don't specify the initialization), and will put it in `bss`; others will just see the fact that there is an initialization, and put it in `data`.

Comment: 'You don't indicate what system, etc., you are using' ->              creating ELF on cortex A15 using codesourcery.                               And I know about the memory segmentation,but as you can see the address neither reside in data nor in bss

Comment: @ritesh What does the linker do if the data don't fit in the size you give?  If it has more than 3MB to put in the data segment, for example?

Comment: the size 3MB is not hard-coded its dynamic,in the linker I include all the input .data and the size is calculated from it.i.e once the data size is calculated. how it could change?