# Global array allocation -- stack or heap?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm compiling the following using Visual Studio 2008 for Windows.

When I declare a global array as such:

```
//.cpp file

// on a global scale
// (i.e. outside any class definition)
MY_ITEM glob_arr[1024];
```

where

```
//.h file
extern MY_ITEM glob_arr[1024];

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        //Start using glob_arr
        glob_arr[0].v = 0;
        //...
    }
};
```

and

```
struct MY_ITEM{
    int v;
    WCHAR chrs[64];
};
```

Where is `glob_arr` allocated -- from the stack or the process heap?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++ terms are automatic, dynamic and static storage. Globals would reside in static storage - how particular implementations deal with this is up to them.

Comment: +1. E.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19540165/1782465) shows an example of one implementation's decision.

Comment: OK, can you explain -- what do you mean by implementation?

Comment: @c00000fd "Implementation" in formal C/C++ terms means: the implementation of a compiler for a specific system.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm using VS 2008 compiler.

Comment: @c00000fd Indeed. This answer here is very generic. On VS the array is definitely stored in static memory. Whether VS refer to this memory as `.bss` or something else, I don't know.

Comment: @Lundin On a typical Unix implementation, the array would be stored in either the `.bss` segment or the `.data` segment, depending on whether it had explicit initialization or not.  I'm pretty sure that Windows behaves in a similar fashion, although I'm not sure about the names of the segments.

Answer (score 2):

It is not stored on the stack nor the heap.

`glob_arr` has *static storage duration* and since you did not initialize it explicitly, it is stored in a read/write RAM segment of your program commonly called `.bss`.

Comment: OK. Appreciate it. The reason I needed to know is because I didn't want to use up limited stack size for my array. But now that it's allocated in static storage, I should probably allocate it from the heap -- even though it involves a bit more core, don't you think?

Comment: @c00000fd No.  You could, of course, but it won't actually change anything.  And why?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Isn't static storage array allocated inside the EXE file image? (Thus making the resulting executable file larger.)

Comment: @c00000fd Not the `.bss` segment.  All that's in the executable is its size.  When loading, the OS will allocate it and initialize it to `0`.  (And who cares about the size of the executable?)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Good point, I didn't know that it was allocated as such. As for the size of the executable file, then a large static array may put its size over the edge. (Unless the modern compilers do "some magic" to prevent that.)

Comment: @c00000fd What do you mean, over the edge?  Obviously, you can't declare an array which won't fit in memory, but then, you can't allocate one dynamically which won't fit in memory either.  And if it will fit in memory, it will certainly fit on disk.

Comment: @JamesKanze: My assumption was that if I declare a static array it will be "reserved" as a part of the executable image file after the code is compiled. Or, in other words, if I declare 1024 int's in a static array, it will add 1024 * 4 bytes to the resulting compiled executable.

Comment: @c00000fd If you declare a static array and explicitly initialize all values to something other than zero, then it will take up more executable space, because those init values will obviously have to be saved in the executable. (In your program's RAM, the array would instead end up in something called `.data`.) That's where there exists a `.bss` segment for zero-init variables: it is kind of a linker optimization.

Comment: @Lundin If I recall it correctly MSVC compiler have never used .bss for user data (even for uninitialized global arrays) and place all the static data into .data! Are you sure it use .bss [now]?

Comment: @c00000fd If you initialize it (e.g. `int x[1000] = { 1 };`), it certainly will.  And?  So does the code you write, and a lot of other things.  I don't see where this could be an issue.  When you run the program, 4K is 4K, regardless of whether it is loaded by copying an image from the executable, allocating and zapping the memory at load time, or allocating and zapping it after the code was loaded.  (The OS will never give you memory that hasn't been zapped somehow.)

Comment: @KonstantinL Interesting.  If you can believe `dumpbin` (and I can't think of a reason not to), VS 2013 doesn't use anything like `.bss` (regardless of the name): both initialized and uninitialized data appears in `.data`, and it looks like there is an image of the uninitialized data.  I don't think it's an issue; but it is strange, because when I compiled, `char x[ 1000000000 ];` compiled and loaded almost instantly, but `char x[ 1000000000 ] = { 1 };` took a very noticeable amount of time (seconds), both for compile and link, and for loading in order to execute.

Comment: @James Kanze Thanx for checking :) It seems strange to me too for long years :)